# list numbering not vertical align with content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to implement an ordered list with a collapsible part inside the `li` elements. The idea is to have some basic information about a given context and by clicking on the link you get further information. The code is working but the numbering (`1.`) is not vertical-align with the content (`Click to collapse`) and I don't know how it can implement that properly. I'm not a css guru, so maybe you can help me.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ol class="list-group list-group-numbered">
    <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
        <div class="ms-2 me-5">
            <div class="fw-bold">
                <a aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                   href="#collapseExample">Click to collpase</a>
            </div>
            some information
        </div>
        <div class="ms-2 ms-5 me-auto">
            some more information
        </div>
        <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">42</span>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Foo, Bar</th>
                <th>Foobar</th>
                <th>FoobarBaz</th>
                <th>Baz</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `list-group-item` grid (add `.d-grid`, `.grid-template`) and make custom grid areas to place inner content to special cells, see Code Snippet CSS part.

Also for shorts in CSS, toggle-button can be wrapped to `.grid-template-toggle` class and collapse block class list can be extended by `.grid-template-collapse`.

```css
.grid-template {
  grid-template-areas: 'num toggle' 'collapse collapse';
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
}

.grid-template:before {
  grid-area: num;
}

.grid-template-toggle {
  grid-area: toggle;
}

.grid-template-collapse {
  grid-area: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ol class="list-group list-group-numbered">
  <li class="list-group-item d-grid grid-template">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start grid-template-toggle">
      <div class="ms-2 me-5">
        <div class="fw-bold">
          <a aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample">Click to collpase</a>
        </div>
        some information
      </div>
      <div class="ms-2 ms-5 me-auto">
        some more information
      </div>
      <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">42</span>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse grid-template-collapse" id="collapseExample">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Foo, Bar</th>
            <th>Foobar</th>
            <th>FoobarBaz</th>
            <th>Baz</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Some Text</td>
            <td>More text text text</td>
            <td>More text text text More text text text</td>
            <td>More text text text More text text text</td>
            <td>More text text text More text text text</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: thx for reply. This is working except there is more `text` inside the table header. Then the upper part of the `li` element jumps back and forth. I replaced the `<thead>` in my code above.

Comment: @aronadaal what do you mean by '..jumps back and forth'? Can you provide examples?

Comment: sure, I added another answer see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72274710/2153744

Try collapsing now ;)

Comment: @aronadaal got it, I'll handle that

Comment: a quick fix could be adding a width to the first cell `<div class="ms-3 me-5" style="width:15rem">`

Comment: @aronadaal here you go, now during collapsing it's not jumbing. I've updated CodeSnippet

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid-template {
  grid-template-areas: 'num toggle' 'collapse collapse';
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
}

.grid-template:before {
  grid-area: num;
}

.grid-template-toggle {
  grid-area: toggle;
}

.grid-template-collapse {
  grid-area: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ol class="list-group list-group-numbered">
    <li class="list-group-item d-grid grid-template">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start grid-template-toggle">
        <div class="ms-2 me-5">
            <div class="fw-bold">
                <a aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                   href="#collapseExample">Click to collpase</a>
            </div>
            some information
        </div>
        <div class="ms-2 ms-5 me-auto">
            some more information
        </div>
        <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">42</span>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse grid-template-collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Foo, Bar</th>
              <th>Foobar</th>
              <th>FoobarBaz</th>
              <th>Baz</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Some Text</td>
                    <td>More text text text</td>
                    <td>More text text text More text text text</td>
                    <td>More text text text More text text text</td>
                    <td>More text text text More text text text</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```